# Javascript parse nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object, nested

I am new to javascript and I am trying to parse and manipulate the data below but not too sure how to go about it. Can anyone help please?

### JSON Data

```
{
    "2009-01": {
        "bbcfour": 324,
        "bbcnews24": 1075,
        "bbcone": 940,
        "bbcthree": 441,
        "bbctwo": 1040,
        "cbbc": 898,
        "cbeebies": 1343
    },
    "2009-02": {
        "bbcfour": 295,
        "bbcnews24": 958,
        "bbcone": 904,
        "bbcthree": 434,
        "bbctwo": 1038,
        "cbbc": 793,
        "cbeebies": 1246
    }}
```

### JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<link href="main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to parse it; jQuery will do that implicitly. What is it that you want to do with the data that you're fetching?

Comment: json is a dictionary structure , means key,value. if you want to read any value use.

jsonobject.key

Comment: I want to be able to take each object e.g. 2009-01 and print its content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `for...in` loop.

The `for..in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.

```
   $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        var resp = data;
        for(k in resp)
        {
          console.log(resp[k].bbcfour);
          console.log(resp[k].bbcnews24);
          console.log(resp[k].bbcone);
          // And so on
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you but i get an 'undefined object' as a result

Comment: should be more like `console.log(data[k].bbcfour);`

Comment: Thanks so much guys, appreciate the help as Im new to this. Thank you